# Why does Guava EventBus not implement an interface?

Tags: guava

I'm currently experiencing a use-case in which I would like to wrap an EventBus instance to provide additional functionality using the decorator pattern. If EventBus would implement an interface this could easily be done. With the current implementation of EventBus (it directly inherits from Object, implements no interfaces) this can only be done by subclassing.

So my question is: is there's a specific reason for not having EventBus implement an interface (e.g. SyncEventBus implements EventBus, AsyncEventBus extends SyncEventBus / implements EventBus)?

Surely, there are some tricks to implement the decorator pattern using subclassing, but specifically with EventBus and it's way to pass events to registered objects, this is relatively complex and not straightforward.

Comment: Mostly because we're still messing with it a lot and we're not necessarily ready to fix an API that we guarantee not to break later.

Comment: I'm currently depending on the class API. What's the difference to depending on the interface API wrt. API breakage?

Besides the extra class, I can currently only see of advantages to having an interface in the hierarchy, especially for extendability. But maybe I'm missing some use case here you're aware of and I'm not?

Comment: If lots of people implement the interface, and then we want to e.g. add methods to the interface, all those people break.  That can't happen if people only use a class API that Guava controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched the Guava issue tracker for you.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=875

Comment: Thanks Google for googling it for me ;-). I guess could have looked it up myself (d'oh).

After reading the discussion I think I'll write my own interface and wrapper to get what I need.